# How to stop Table within a Table inheriting style of first table?

Tags: css, css-tables

Ok first off I am not styling page with tables or anything like that, just want to get that out of the way, lol.

Basically I have a table that lists services, prices, and add to cart paypal buttons.

Everything works fine and looks great, except I am using two inline styles, that I would like to bring to an external style sheet instead.

The reason I am using the inline styles: One of the paypal buttons has a drop down option menu...that option menu is made from a . All the paypal buttons including the one with the option menu are inside of my main table, so the paypal with option button is creating a table within a table that is inheriting the styles set for my main table.  The style is a border that goes around the option button.

The only way I can stop it, is by using inline styles.

I tried adding some CSS that sets the border to none:

```
.noborder {border:none;}
```

then add HTML class to the paypal td section: , but that does not work. Only inline style stops border like this:

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am trying to post the html here and it is not letting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your same css solution, but forcing the style with `!important`, like this:

```
.noborder {border:none !important;}
```

Comment: I tried to use the: .noborder {border:none !important} it did not work.

Comment: Ok, although you're missing a semicolon in the code of your comment, so make sure you tested my version (with semicolon).

Comment: OMG it works!!! thanks for pointing out the missing ";" is it frowned apon using: "!important"? I know you really don't want to be using inline styles, but never really knew about the !important class till now.

Comment: Yes `!important` is very useful for inline styles, you can read about it  in http://www.yellowjug.com/web-design/the-importance-of-important-in-css/

Comment: @Rob you seem new to StackOverflow, welcome!, and remember to accept the answer (green mark) so both me and you get rewarded points. thanks!

Comment: Cool article I just read up some more on the !important class i guess you would call it, and it seems really cool. It seems people are split on it being a no-no or a valuable tool. I had this problem for about 2 days now and tried everything, do you think there is any other work around besides the !important? just wondering

Comment: If it's only one element you will apply the style, you could also try with applying the style by ID, like `#elementid {border:none;}` but otherwise the `!important` solution would be what I'd use in your case.

Comment: Ok the ID worked too. I thought I tried that already, guess not. Two more EASY questions then I am done. 1. So i got both working ID and !important, which one would you use and why? 2. How do you accept the answer i don't see the green mark...i think you just click on the check mark and then it turns green?

Comment: 1. I would use the ID solution as it's cleaner because you can avoid the inline style and put it in your general css file along with rest of page styles.  2. Yes I mean to check the mark so it gets green then it's accepted.